# Como recuperar conteúdo de um cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

Como faço para recuperar o conteúdo de um cookie, esse cookie tem o ID do material que será solicitado e a quantidade, preciso recuperar para inserir no banco. Já procurei muito na internet e ainda não achei como fazer isso.
Segue o codigo de como eu crio o cookie e insiro os valores nele.

```
    [Authorize]
    public void AddCarrinho(String Qtd, String Id)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie;
        if(Request.Cookies["pedido"] == null)
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie("pedido");
        }
        else
        {
            cookie = (HttpCookie)Request.Cookies["pedido"];
        }
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1); //cookie expira depois de 1 hora
        cookie.Values.Add(Id, Qtd);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

**Editado**

Segue o codigo de como eu fiz  após a resposta do Cigano Morison e não deu certo.

```
    public void AddCarrinho(String Id, String Qtd)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie;
        if (Request.Cookies["teste"] == null)
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie("teste");
        }
        else
        {
            cookie = (HttpCookie)Request.Cookies["teste"];
        }
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1); //cookie expira depois de 1 hora
        cookie.Values.Add(Id, Qtd);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }

    public ActionResult Recuperar()
    {
        Teste t = new Teste();

        List<Teste> lst = new List<Teste>();

        if(Request.Cookies["teste"]["Id"] != null && Request.Cookies["teste"]["Qtd"] != null)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < Request.Cookies.Count; i++)
            {
                t.ID = Request.Cookies["teste"]["Id"];
                t.Quantidade = Request.Cookies["teste"]["Qtd"];
                lst.Add(t);
            }
        }

        return View(lst);
    }
```

**Editado**

[image: Debug]

Answer (score 2):

Um Cookie é um dicionário, logo:

```
if (Request.Cookies["pedido"][Id] != null) 
{ 
    minhaInformacao = Request.Cookies["pedido"][Id]; 
}
```

Comment: Cigano, eu editei a pergunta e postei o código de como eu fiz, não deu certo, veja se tem alguma coisa errado por favor. Obrigado.

Comment: @AlanAlmeida No momento que você executa `Recuperar`, quando você inspeciona `Request.Cookies`, o que tem dentro dela?

Comment: Quer que eu poste um print da tela pra você ver?

Comment: @AlanAlmeida Pode ser. Eu preciso saber o que tem dentro da variável.

Comment: Esta adicionado, editei a pergunta.

Comment: @AlanAlmeida `AllKeys` não diz nada. Você precisa expandir o enumerável através da propriedade `Result` pra ver o que tem preenchido.

Comment: você se refere a ultima opção que tem o nome de Result View? se for, tem o mesmo resultado [0] "teste"